# Fitness activity data

Tags: data-request, sports

Seems like something easy to find, but somehow I have hit a brick wall. I am trying to find data set with list of exercises and meta data - exercise name, difficulty, picture, description. Preferably in JSON format.

```
{
    "title": "Pull-up",
    "description": "Pull yourself up against horizontal bar fixed above your head.",
    "muscles": ["shoulders", "arms", "back"],
    "equipment": "Pull-up Bar",
    "difficulty": "hard",
    "picture": "/img/dude-makeing-a-pull-up.png"
}
```

I found a Reddit post with scraped data from bodybuilding.com, but I obviously can't use that for legal reasons.

I tried googling, but all I get is some programming exercises.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing this link here is, indirectly, in my opinion, a way to promote/support the violation of bodybuilding.com terms of use. (this is stolen data)

I suggest you to edit your post and remove the link. However it's an interesting topic.

Comment: I did mention that this is unusable data for that reason. Script used to get that data is trivial. I don't think that me taking it out would stop anyone. However, only reason for that link is to illustrate what data I would to get and you have a solid point, so I will remove it.